# How to convert ReadOnlyMemory<char> to ReadOnlyMemory<byte>

Tags: c#, memory-management, stream

As far as I know, the `Memory<T>` is a contiguous area of memory, and `<T>` just indicates that what type this memory stream is referring to. Presumably, it should be feasible to convert `Memory<T>` to `Memory<K>` and `ReadOnlyMemory<T>` to `ReadOnlyMemory<K>` and also `ReadOnlyMemory<char>` to `ReadOnlyMemory<byte>`
But I don't see a way to convert it **without first Convert it to an array and then load it into a new `Memory<k>`**, or some thing like this which will sacrifice memory and CPU-time.
Is that kind of *On-the-fly* conversion possible at all?

Comment: How would you expect `char` to convert to `byte` though? It's not a simple cast.

Comment: char can be (actually is) 2 bytes long

Comment: For 8 bit character I simply cast input.Select(x => (byte)x).ToArray();

Comment: @jdweng Multiple things wrong with that comment. Firstly OP doesn't want to use memory, that's the entire point of the question. Secondly, you cannot simply cast a `char` to a `byte`. Please don't suggest things like this.

Comment: In addition "Presumably, it should be feasible to convert Memory<T> to Memory<K>". I'm not an expert but: That's not how that works. When you find a "T" inside a Memory<T> (error, in the end Span<T> is who makes the deal), it finds the whole T structure from "the last T last byte" if it not find (padding, inner types, etc...) it will throw an exception (I suppose CastException, but I'm not sure, like I said I'm not an expert in this)

Comment: With `Span<>` it is easy: `char[] arr = new char[10]; var sp = new ReadOnlySpan<char>(arr); var sp2 = MemoryMarshal.Cast<char, byte>(sp);`

Comment: @DavidG : You are wrong.  The following code works :            char[] c = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
            byte[] b = c.Select(x => (byte)x).ToArray();

Comment: @jdweng Just because your code runs without throwing an exception doesn't mean it worked. Now take a look at this code, run it and explain to me how the output is like that. Then for bonus points, write some code that will translate the byte array back into a char array... https://rextester.com/CGLP64983

Comment: @DavidG : I know exactly what is does and used it more than once.

Comment: @jdweng So can you explain my code?

Comment: @DavidG [don't bother](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392514/what-can-i-do-about-a-user-consistently-spreading-misinformation).

Comment: @CodeCaster I know, I'm not trying to convince him to change because I know he won't, but a third party looking in on this might be swayed to not use his dangerous advice.

Comment: There is nothing dangerous with casting types.  It is done all the time providing you know what you are doing.  Everybody casts floating point numbers to integers (or rounding) when needed.  Eight bit Characters and Bytes are exactly the same except for the type.

Comment: @jdweng without testing the characters first, you won't know whether it's safe to cast them to bytes. And again, you're missing the point of the question: creating a new array, you require more memory, which is exactly what the OP is trying to prevent. And they are not exactly the same, a `char` is two bytes, a `byte` is one.

Comment: @CodeCaster : You may be making the problem harder than it actually is.  If you know your input is English character than you do not have to worry about unicode characters.  You are making an assumption that you know nothing about your inputs.  When you get a problem you must know the requirements and you are totally ignoring the requirements.

Comment: @jdweng sure, if you can be certain that this code will always process characters with a code point below 256, it won't break. Until the day that the next developer or a new input source comes along, and then it causes hard to find bugs. It's fragile code based on a dangerous assumption. Especially lower-level code that casts or interprets chars as bytes should make no assumptions about the contents of those bits.